# Is there an enum for day, week, month, and year?

Tags: c#, .net, time, enums

Im looking to store time frequency represented as daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly as an `enum` and was wondering if one already existed within the C# library?

An example would be wanting to keep track of whether the interest on a loan is charged every day, each week, each month, etc.

Comment: @8protons - I agree that it doesn't seem that useful to use an `enum`. It would create a brittle part of your code. Say someone wants to add `Fortnightly` or `Biannually` or even `FirstTuesdayOfEachMonth` and then you'll need to recompile your entire code-base. What's worse is that there's logic that you'd need to add for each value in the `enum` so you'd be adding that too. Why not just make the logic code the only thing you need to add? Create a `IFrequency` interface that has `string Name`, `DateTime GetNext(DateTime anchor)`, etc, and you can then just drop in a new assembly when required.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, such an enum doesn't exist by default in the framework, but you can easily create one yourself:

```
enum Periodicity {
   Daily,
   Weekly,
   Monthly,
   Annually
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such enum in TaskScheduler class but it too lacks Yearly. I hope creating a new enum would be a right option.